# Can I have a full height 2nd row taking into account the height of the 1st row in a grid layout?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have two full width rows. The first one has top and bottom padding so that it has a height. The other must be full height minus the height of the first one.

I used CSS grid layout (even if I have only one column, I don't want to make use of the flexbox layout, for personal reasons):

```
.main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-areas:
        'menu'
        'section_1';
}

.menu {
    grid-area: menu;
}

.section_1 {
    grid-area: section_1;
}
```

I would want to replace `1fr` by something that would allow my second row, named `section_1`, to  be full height minus `menu`'s height without using `calc(100vh - <menu_height>)`. Is it possible? I've tried `1fr` but it doesn't work for this purpose of course.

Comment: fr means fraction , so you need to set the ratio of fractions of both elements, js will help you here ... but if you don't set any row template it will do without. Can you clarify the use with a snippet with enough code to demonstrate your issue . If you set an height on .main, it will also do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to complete comment untill clarification:

> `fr` means fraction , so you need to set the ratio of fractions of both elements, js will help you here ... but if you don't set any row template it will do without. Can you clarify the use with a snippet with enough code to demonstrate your issue . If you set an `height` on `.main`, it will also do the job

are you looking for this :

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  height: 100vh;/* missing in your code */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-areas: 'menu' 'section_1';
}

nav {
  grid-area: menu;
}

section {
  background: #bee;
  grid-area: section_1;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <nav> a nav</nav>
  <section> a section </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Perfect, my mistake was: I forgot the `(min-)height: 100vh` :) ty! Just another question about your answer: in fact, I will have more than only one section. Some of them won't be heighted with exactly 100vh ; their height will be set up by their content. So I can't fix a height for the grid (in other words I won't use `(min-)height: 100vh` ). In this context, must I use `calc` in `grid-template-rows` as I briefly mentioned in my question?

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler would this be morelike your trouble : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64769810/is-there-a-way-to-shrink-an-element-with-set-height/64772002

Comment: T'y I will take a look asap:)